# Launch full screen video with vuforia and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

For a project I need to launch a full screen video when a vuforia marker is detected.

I am able to launch the video on a plane placed over the marker but not to play it full screen.
I have also tried to use the Video Player to play full screen but this way only the audio is played and not the image.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you very much.